# Wordpress - won't to redirect to subpage in menu

Tags: wordpress, menu

I have installed wordpress and add my own theme. It works right.
But I have problem with menu. In table `wp_terms` I have records:

```
1 - without category
2 - sports
3 - action
..
```

In meny on main site I have links like: `http://mydomain/category/sports`

And when I click on menu item it redirect me to the empty site:
`mydomain/category/sports` was not found on this server.  And I get `404 error`.

This is my `mod_rewrite`

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

Comment: Are your settings>permalinks set to something other that "default"? Otherwise, the links won't work.

Comment: In settings Entry name is checked and url looks:   http://example.com/sample-entry/

Comment: Try clicking "Save" in the seetings>permalinks page, sometimes that works.

Comment: Sometimes but not this time

Comment: The only other things I can think off is that perhaps your server doesn't have the mod_rewrite module enabled or that a bad plugin (try disabling them).